# MongoDB query distinct fields, no matter of values (slow query analysis)

Tags: mongodb

I have turned on profiling of slow queries on MongoDB, after couple of days I have plenty of data. What I want to do is to get profiling records distinct by: namespace (collection name) and fields used for filtering.

Is there any way how to write query to get distinct records based on field names (and not values)?

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "myLovelyDb.Stuff",
    "query" : {
        "find" : "Stuff",
        "filter" : {
            "StartTime" : {
                "$lt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T16:01:31.000Z")
            },
            "EndTime" : {
                "$gt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T16:01:31.000Z")
            }
        }
        ...
    }
},
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "myLovelyDb.Stuff",
    "query" : {
        "find" : "Stuff",
        "filter" : {
            "StartTime" : {
                "$lt" : ISODate("1999-07-04T16:01:31.000Z")
            },
            "EndTime" : {
                "$gt" : ISODate("1999-07-04T16:01:31.000Z")
            }
        }
        ...
    }
},
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "myLovelyDb.Stuff",
    "query" : {
        "find" : "Stuff",
        "filter" : {
            "ParentId" : {
                "$ne" : 666
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

... so I get only 2 records from this set (which should be enough to be able to add indexes on columns).

db.getCollection('system.profile').find({op:"query"}).sort({millis:-1})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I figured out I can still use aggregation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) so here it comes:

```
db.system.profile.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "millis": {
                "$gt": 300
            },
            "op": "query"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "collection": "$query.find",
                "command": "$command",
                "op": "$op"
            },
            "avgTime": {
                $avg: "$millis"
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            },
            "execStats": {
                $first: "$execStats"
            },
            "query": {
                $first: "$query"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "avgTime": -1
        }
    }
])
```

You can tweak match/grouping as you wish.